# Gujarti text on html Page

Tags: java, html, character-encoding, webfonts

In my Project I have to display a text in Gujarati Font on HTML page so, can anyone help me how can i do this?

I will explain you how my application read Gujarati String.

Steps :

1) Upload MsWord document(with Gujarti content) from jsp page and store it in MySQl table with hibernate.

2) Retrieve document by java/hibernate and display back to HTML page.

Now, problem is HTML page can no display this Gujarati font. I have used UTF-8 encoding also.

Comment: You should start by telling whether you have problems with a static page in Gujarati, too, or whether the problem comes up with MySQL. If MySQL is relevant, it should be added to the tags. Does the problem occur when not using webfonts? If the problem is specific to using webfonts, what kind of webfont are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following line in your HTML.

< meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />